# A simple question about counting possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\ge 3$ be a natural number. How many possibilities do we have to find 3 **odd** natural numbers $k_1,k_2,k_3>0$ such that $k_1+k_2+k_3\leq n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want $2a+1+2b+1+2c+1\leq n$ so $2a+2b+2c\leq n-3$ so $a+b+c\leq \lfloor \frac{n-3}{2}\rfloor$.

The number of solutions in non-negative integers to $a+b+c\leq x$ is clearly equal to the number of solutions in non-negative integers to $a+b+c+d=x$, by stars and bars this is $\binom{x+3}{3}$.

So you want $\binom{\lfloor (n-3)/2 \rfloor +3}{3}$.